# Why Arc<dyn Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync> doesn't have syze known at compile time

Tags: rust

```
use std::sync::Arc;
pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;

pub struct B {
    a: A,
}
```

Gives

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut [u8]) + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:5:8
  |
5 |     a: A,
  |        ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut [u8]) + 'static)`
  = note: only the last element of a tuple may have a dynamically sized type
```

I think `Arc` has a size know at compile time. `dyn Fn` has, at least when I do `pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;`. However, when I put `dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8])` inside `dyn Dn`, the size cannot be known.

Why `pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn() -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;` is ok but not `pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a little unhelpful because it's directing you to the wrong part of the type.

> `dyn Fn` has [a size]

Like any "bare" trait object, `dyn Fn` is *not* sized. However this is ok because `Arc<T>` does not require `T: Sized`.

The issue is that `dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8])` is unsized, so the you can't have `Fn(dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize)`. It is not allowed for a function argument to be unsized.

Making that function argument `Sized` will fix the problem, e.g.

```
pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn(&dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;
//                      ^--- added &
```

---

It's worth [reporting a bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+diagnostics), so that this error message can be improved.

Comment: I think this is just [Trait bounds are not checked on type aliases until they are used](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51626).

Comment: @trentcl Maybe, but see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9dd190bf7b8d94d31fda5c1ab24b66a). The error message underlines the entire type, not just the inner `FnOnce`.

Comment: While `&dyn FnOnce(...)` compiles as a type definition, you won't be able to actually _call_ the inner closure because calling a `FnOnce` needs to consume the closure, which is impossible if it's behind a reference. Possible solutions (that I'm aware  of) are outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579120/1600898) to the OP's other question the OP explains the intended usage of the type.

Answer (score 0):

error messages (rust 1.50)

```
help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn for<'r> FnOnce(&'r mut [u8]) + 'static)`
note: only the last element of a tuple may have a dynamically sized type
```

[FnOnce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/function.rs.html#219-228) trait takes Args as generic type and Args may be converted from tuple internally (my guess :).

but, we can't make tuple like (dynamic sized, sized)

Your code can be fixed using &dyn FnOnce (which is sized) or swap argument positions

```
pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn(&dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8]), usize) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;
// or
pub type A = Arc<dyn Fn(usize, dyn FnOnce(&mut [u8])) -> Result<(), ()> + Send + Sync>;
```